# Speculative questions - what to do?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/android-lte-phones-available-in-the-pipeline

(Not picking on the questioner. I've seen several such questions; this is just the most recent.)

I just wonder if this is the type of question we want here. It's basically asking us to parse the news for the asker.

It just doesn't "feel" quite right to me. (Maybe I should go see what the [Apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com) people are doing.)

Comment: Apple equivalent - "What phone is coming soon" - answer: "iPhone 5" no speculation! ;)

Comment: @GAThrawn from the past, except that it turns out I was wrong :(

Answer (score 3):

> It's basically asking us to parse the news for the asker.

As opposed to any other question that is asking us to parse [google|internet|personal experience] ?

But speculative questions have no one right answer until the *future* is **past**. In that sense, they may be *worse* than community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty open to what I consider useful subjective questions, but this doesn't query the communities Android expertise or any information about using or getting the most out of and Android device, it is just question for newsers and android blog enthusiasts.  I think this is off topic.

Asking, "Will my XXX phone be able to use Verizon's LTE network" is a good question.

Comment: Okay, you make a good point. But what do we *do* about it?

Comment: Good question Al.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion to answer Al's question about what we should do about it...

If the question is salvageable then leave a comment directing the asker on how to improve/edit the question to fit within the scope of the site.  If they don't do it, then we should fix it if possible.

If it's un-salvageable then close/delete/migrate it.

In this case I think without the asker changing it to a more specific question it's un-salvageable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's another take that is contrary to my two previous answers and more consistent with Michaels point:

This is a community of Android Experts and Enthusiasts.  Searching google for answers to question like the one you posted can be very confusing and fruitless because of all the speculation.  This community of users is uniquely qualified to filter through a lot of that speculation and provide a more coherent answer to a noob.  In many cases a lot of us have already done that by religiously reading the Android news sites, blogs and forums to satisfy our own interests.

Comment: The problem is not that we're not qualified or capable to answer such questions, it's just that compared to solving real problems, these questions are actually really crappy and tend to be asked more frequently and for every model known to man. So if users want this info: they should come to chat or you can have certain announcement posts on Meta as @Al has made before